# Detecting a failed login in Cake

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

Greetings!

I'm relatively new to CakePHP and I'm mostly working on my authentication pages right now. I thought it'd be cool if I could record how many times a user failed to log in, so I was wondering if it was possible to detect when a login failed to authenticate...

Does anybody know if that's possible?

Comment: are you using cake auth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put that logic into your `UsersController::login` function:

```
function login() {
    if ($this->data) { // login form was submitted
        if (!$this->Auth->user()) { // login failed
            // do something about it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I figured that might have something to do with it. Thank you! :)