# How to count login attempts in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication, login-attempts

I'm developing application with CakePHP 1.3 and using its Auth component. Is it possible to count login fails in order to deactivate users account after a few unsuccessfull attempts? Is there anything like loginErrorRedirect?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206146/detecting-a-failed-login-in-cake/5208137#5208137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you intending to deactivate a user if they can't login? If they login as

test@test.com FAIL
tester@test.com FAIL
test123@test.com FAIL

are you going to invalidate all these users?

To record login failures, your could add the following to your login() action in whatever controller

```
if(empty($this->Session->Auth) && isset($this->data))
{
    if($this->Session->read('login.fail'))
    {
        $login_fail = $this->Session->read('login.fail') + 1;
    }else{
        $login_fail = 1;
    }
    $this->Session->write("login.fail",$login_fail);
}
```

Comment: No, I'm going to deactivate users account after three fail attempts on this single account. So: test@test.com - fail, test@test.com - fail, test@test.com - fail, lock. Anyway it seems condition you gave me in first line of your code is only solution.

Comment: An attacker just needs to remove cookies after each failed attempt and he'll be able to try forever.